# How to filter the inbound packet by libpcap in C

Tags: c++, wireshark, ethernet, pcap, libpcap

Recently I am trying to filter the inbound packet from the pcap file by libpcap in C/C++.
Here is partial code.

```
  pcap = pcap_open_offline(argv[0], errbuf);
  if (pcap == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "error reading pcap file: %s\n", errbuf);
    exit(1);
  }

  char filter_exp[] = "inbound";
  struct bpf_program pgm;
  if (pcap_compile(pcap, &pgm, filter_exp, 0, PCAP_NETMASK_UNKNOWN) == -1) {
    printf("Bad filter - %s\n", pcap_geterr(pcap));
    return 1;
  }

  if (pcap_setfilter(pcap, &pgm) == -1) {
    printf("Error setting filter - %s\n", pcap_geterr(pcap));
    return 1;
  }
```

But the error message is as following.

> Bad filter - inbound/outbound not supported on linktype 1 when reading savefiles

Is there any way that can filter inbound packet in C/C++ ?

Comment: the "inbound" filter is not available for the Ethernet link type (a cooked capture would have it eg.). Is it sufficient for your needs to filter on destination MAC or IP address ?

Comment: Sorry that I am just a beginner. But how to distinguish target IP address is local in savefile?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: Thanks for your suggestions. Here is a related one talks about "How to determine the inbound packets for Ethernet link type from pcap file" - (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50884335/inbound-outbound-not-supported-on-linktype-1-when-reading-savefiles)